# Unable to access variable name corresponding to register RTX in gcc

Tags: gcc, plugins, gcc4.7

Is it possible to access the variable name if we have an RTX which is a reg that corresponds to a variable declared by the user in GCC?

> I have found the macro `REG_USERVAR_P (RTX)` in `rtl.h` which returns the boolean "1 if RTX is a reg that corresponds to a variable declared by the user." But I am unable to get a suitable macro to get the variable name the reg corresponds to.

On dumping the rtl output using the command

`print_rtl_single(stdout, in_rtx);`

I get output:

`(reg/v:SI 68 [ c ])`

where `c` was the variable name defined by me. How do I access `c` given the rtx statement, `in_rtx`?

Answer (score 0):

To access the c in your example usethe command:

```
if (REG_EXPR(in_rtx))
  print_mem_expr (stdout, REG_EXPR (in_rtx));
```